# Sum of hours between multiple dates without one row type

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, date-arithmetic

I need to add up the time but subtracting the time when the status is "STOP". Can I make a SQL query or do I need to combine SQL + PHP? I was given such a database. Statuses can repeat themselves

MariaDB 10.5.11,
PHP 7.4.5

```
ID Date                 Status

1  2020.11.02 15:00     New 
1  2020.11.02 15:00     New_Step 
1  2020.11.02 15:05     Start 
1  2020.11.02 15:05     Stop   
1  2020.11.02 15:10     Start
1  2020.11.02 15:15     Transferred
1  2020.11.02 15:20     Stop
1  2020.11.02 16:25     End  
2  2020.11.02 16:00     New 
2  2020.11.02 16:00     Start 
2  2020.11.02 16:05     Stop   
2  2020.11.02 16:10     Start
2  2020.11.02 16:15     Stop   
2  2020.11.02 16:20     Start
2  2020.11.02 16:25     New_Step 
3  2020.11.02 16:30     Transferred
2  2020.11.02 16:35     End
```

I need to get this result

```
ID SumTime
1  15 min
2  25 min
```

I need add new status "Transferred and New_Step" to this query

```
SELECT t1.ID, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t1.`Date`,t2.`Date`)) complsum
FROM (SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `ID` ORDER BY `Date` ASC) AS row_num 
FROM table1 WHERE `Status` =  'Start') t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `ID` ORDER BY `Date` ASC) AS row_num 
FROM table1 WHERE `Status`  IN ('Stop','End')) t2 
ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.`row_num` =  t2.`row_num`
GROUP BY t1.ID
```

Comment: Explain in details how the desired output is obtained from shown source data.

Comment: ```ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `ID` ORDER BY `Date` ASC)``` - Date values within partition are not unique, so the expression makes no sense.

Comment: Each status must be summed up except for the "STOP" statuses (then the time is not counted)

Comment: *Each status must be summed up* `Status` is a string - it cannot be summed up.

Comment: I mean adding up the time based on the date of each status

Comment: Subtracting time on stop doesn't seem to be what you want if I check your totals against the column. What you mean is that the time in between a Stop event and the next non-Stop event must not be counted.

Comment: @RoAchterberg Exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count all intervals whose starting status is not "Stop". You can just use `lead()` and date artithmetics:

```
select id, sum(timestampdiff(minute, date, lead_date)) sumtime
from (
    select t.*, lead(date) over(partition by id order by date) lead_date
    from mytable t
) t
where status <> 'Stop'
group by id
```

Note that for this to consistently work, you need each `date`s to be unique - otherwise the ordering of the events it undefined for duplicates - or, at least, you need another criteria to break the date ties, such as an auto-incrementing primary key for example.

Here is a **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c221517b8b2c47968b1359de6ee5429)** that demonstrates how the query works, with a primary key added to the `order by` of the subquery.

Comment: As I have said in comments, `Date` is not unique... LEAD() output is unpredictable. You must specify RANGE window as a palliative.

Comment: @Akina: yes. Even a `RANGE` window is not safe here I believe, if we don't have a stable sort criteria. I added a disclaimer about that in my answer, and a recommendation on how to fix it.

Comment: Yes, we have not stable sorting for both current and "previous" timepoint. So RANGE window plus additional window ordering by `Status = 'Stop'` needed.

Comment: @Akina: that's one way to do it, but we are not even sure that's really the ordering OP wants. They need to sort this out, based on the pointers provided in the answer.

Comment: As I understand OP needs to sum up all adjacent intervals lengths where none final row is 'Stopped'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the logic, but maybe you need in

```sql
WITH cte AS (SELECT ID, `Date`
             FROM test
             GROUP BY ID, `Date`
             -- remove timepoint where status is 'Stop' for at least one row
             HAVING !SUM(Status = 'Stop'))

SELECT ID, 
       -- Calculate points amount and multiply by 5, adjust points to ranges between points
       CONCAT(5 * COUNT(`Date`) - 5, ' min')
FROM cte
GROUP BY id;
```

?

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=c0ef137a018557a6b814f7f723d3d859)

Comment: Suppose you have an application that has stages. You can start them, stop them, transfer them, etc. I want to count the reporting time, but when the time is in "Stop" status, the time  is not counted

Comment: @ArekGryglewicz If so, and if you GUARANTEE that no skipped timepoints, then my solution must give correct result.